# Сортировка строк в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c#

Есть свой List - как  реализовать,чтобы слова были в алфавитном порядке от 1-ой буквы

Comment: [Order By](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: List<T>.Sort (Comparison<T>) - метод сортировки которому можно указать свою функцию сравнения, в ней можно указать сравнивать начиная с 1й буквы.

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка по алфавиту:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>()
{
    new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 },
    new User { Name = "Bob", Age = 30 },
    new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 21 },
    new User { Name = "Sam", Age = 43 }
};
var result = from user in users
             orderby user.Name, user.Age, user.Name.Length
             select user;
foreach (User u in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", u.Name, u.Age);
```

Результат:

```
Alice - 28
Bob - 30
Sam - 43
Tom - 21
Tom - 33
```